# Basis of $\textbf{R}^2$ which consists entirely of eigenvectors of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of  $\textbf{R}^2$ which consists entirely of eigenvectors of A, where A= 
$$
\left[\begin{matrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

I found the eigenvalues are -1 and 3.

Comment: Your next step is trying to find the eigenvectors of $A$. By definition, the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. You'll have to solve a linear system.

Comment: You might want to review the post [Eigenvector basis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146788/eigenvector-basis?rq=1) to model the process of finding the eigenvectors given your eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A (non-trivial) eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $\lambda$ is a non-zero vector in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$. Do you know how to find a basis for a matrix's null space? If so, you should be able to find appropriate eigenvectors.